# Click event on a slider goes at the end of the array

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I am trying to create a simple slider using javascript.
So far, here is my code :

html:

```
  <div class="carousel-container">

    <div class="slides-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="assets/images/image-1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="assets/images/image-3.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="assets/images/image-2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="assets/images/image-3.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="carousel-nav">
    <button class="button-previous">Previous</button>
    <button class="button-next">Next</button>
  </div>
```

Js :

```
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide')
    const slidesContainer = document.querySelector('.slides-container')
    const slidesCount = slides.length
    const slideWidth = slides[0].clientWidth

    const prevButton = document.querySelector('.button-previous')
    const nextButton = document.querySelector('.button-next')

    function nextSlide(slide) {
      for (slide = 0; slide < slidesCount; slide++) {
        slidesContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + (slide * slideWidth) + 'px)'
      }
    }

    nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      nextSlide()
    })
```

The issue I have is that when I click on the next button, the slider goes all the way at the end of my array, thus skipping all the images in between.

What would be the best way to have my for loop stop at each image and go again when the button is clicked?

Comment: Are you trying to get it to stop on each slide briefly before landing on the "next" slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is skipping to the end with each click is: the `for()` loop. You are cycling through *all* of the slides — generating a new `translateX` coordinate with each pass – on *every* click. Leaving you with the last value every time.

The answer [CheapGamer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7276273/cheapgamer) gave defines a pattern to avoid the `for()` loop trap by keeping track of the current “slide” index *outside* of the `nextSlide()` handler.

```
let current = 0; // <- independent index reference

function nextSlide(slide) {
      if (current < slidesCount) {
        slidesContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + (current * slideWidth) + 'px)';
        current++;  // <- increment the index
      }
}
// I changed the `slide` reference in `(slide * slideWidth)` to `current`  to reflect the intent of the code
```

This takes care of incrementing you through the carousel until `current` equals `3`. (The `slide` argument in `nextSlide(slide)` isn’t necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

```
let current = 0;

function nextSlide(slide) {
      if (current < slidesCount) {
        slidesContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + (slide * slideWidth) + 'px)';
        current++;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might not exactly understand what you try to do or why you intend to use a for loop but if it's just about selecting the next slide you may go with this:

```
var currentSlide = 0;

function nextSlide() {
  //make sure currentSlide is in range
  currentSlide = (currentSlide >= slidesCount) ? 0 : ++currentSlide;

  slidesContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + (currentSlide * slideWidth) + 'px)';
}

nextButton.addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
```

or a little bit more flexible:

```
var currentSlide = 0;

function nextSlide(direction /* Number */) {
  if(!direction) direction = 1; //default

  setSlide(currentSlide + direction % slidesCount);
}

function setSlide(index) {
  if(index === currentSlide) return;

  //make sure index is in range
  while(index >= slidesCount) index -= slidesCount;
  while(index < 0) index += slidesCount;

  slidesContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + (index * slideWidth) + 'px)';

  currentSlide = index;
}

nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  nextSlide(this.dataset["direction"]); //by using data you don't need two different button classes
});
```

But if you insist on using a loop I'm afraid to tell that it's inappropriate in this case since the calculation of translateX is based on a given value.